# How to properly delete a Google Apis Console project?

Tags: android, google-api, project, google-drive-api

I'm  having a problem deleting a project from the Google Apis Console. According to [Google APIs Console Help](https://developers.google.com/console/help/?hl=bg#deletingaproject) a project can be undeleted during the 7 days after a deletion, after that the project becomes inaccessible.

For me the problem is that the project can be undeleted for more than a month now (I think I deleted it at the end of November). When I'm using my android app I can still access Google Drive (Drive API is the only enabled service in the project). This project was created just to test the app with my personal google account but now I need the package name and certificate fingerprint for the project in the "official account".

So - any idea what I could have done wrong deleting the project?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have done anything wrong, permanent project (and client credentials) deletion is currently being worked on and should land into production soon.

Comment: Thanks! I guess with "client credentials" you mean the package name and the certificate fingerprint?

Comment: Yes, the package name/fingerprint pair so that it can be reused